# Where is the sample audio Swansong, Josh Woodward on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

i cant find it, already googled it and i found something with `/usr/share/example-content/etc..` but this directory doesn't exists in my installation.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file can be found with a `find` search as follows:

```
andrew@ithaca:~$ find /usr -iname *swansong*
/usr/share/example-content/Ubuntu_Free_Culture_Showcase/Josh Woodward - Swansong.ogg
```

This file is part of the [Ubuntu Free Culture Showcase](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFreeCultureShowcase) initiative, a very worthwhile initiative and competition. The song is "Swansong" from the 2009 album Breadcrumbs, composed and sung by Josh Woodward, and it was the winner of the Ubuntu Free Culture Showcase 10.10.

If you don't have the file at all it can be installed as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install example-content
```

The file list (from Wily) of this package can be [seen here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/all/example-content/filelist).

**References:**

- [File:Josh Woodward - Swansong.ogg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Josh_Woodward_-_Swansong.ogg)
- [Ubuntu 10.10’s Free Culture showcase selections](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/ubuntu-10-10s-free-culture-showcase-selections)

Comment: in fact, i didn't found with the `find`, but the apt-get method did worked.
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The name of the file seems to be "Josh Woodward - Swansong.ogg" according to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2122766. I did `sudo find / -name *Swansong.ogg` on my lubuntu 15.10, and did not find anything. Maybe it was removed since trusty or earlier.